# How to convert List<Map> to List<MyModel>

Tags: flutter

I have a List as picture:

[image: List]

My model is:

```
class ChartData {
  DateTime time = DateTime.now();
  double value = 0;

  ChartData({required this.time, required this.value});

  factory ChartData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ChartData(
        time: json['time'],
        value: json['value'],
      );
}
```

I tried to use

```
var chartData = diData.map((e) => ChartData.fromJson(e)).toList();
```

to convert `List<ChartData>` but after convert, all elements are '0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert time to `DateTime` object in Dart.

```
  factory ChartData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ChartData(
        time: DateTime.parse(json['time'] as String),
        value: json['value'],
      );
```

Then you can convert `diData` to `List<ChartData>`.

```
 List<ChartData> list = diData.map((e)=>ChartData.fromJson(e as Map<String,dynamic>)).toList();
```